# Non-metrizability of specific polyhedron by showing that first countability axiom fails (Munkres ETA, exercise 2.4, p. 14)

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $K$ be a collection of one simplices $\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\ldots$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where each vertex $\sigma_i$ has vertices $(0,0)$ and $(1,1/i)$. This collection $K$ of $1$-simplicies constutes a simplicial complex. Why is $|K|\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ (called a polyhedron) not metrizable?

Given the hint in the book,  it suffices to show that the first countability axiom fails. Every metrizable space is first countable. First countability requires that for each point $P$ in a topological there exists a countable sequence of neighbourhoods $(N_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for each neighbourhood $N$ of $P$, there exists an $i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $N_i\subset N$. I cannot see which point violates this condition, i.e. for which point in $|K|$ there exists no such countable neighbourhood basis.

Comment: I find it strange to claim that a subset of the Euclidean plane is non-metrizable. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Arthur It is metrizable as a subspace of ${\bf R}^2$ but Munkres (and not Mumkres) puts another topology on polyedron with infinitely many simplices.

Comment: @Arthur yes, coudy is right, the underlying topology assumes that a subset $A$ is closed if the intersection with each simplex ($A\cap\sigma$) is closed in each simplex $\sigma\in K$.

Answer (score 3):

The space $X = \lvert K \rvert$ does not have the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R^2$, but the topology which is defined by

- $U \subset X$ is open in $X$ iff $U \cap \sigma_i$ is open in $\sigma_i$ for all $i$.

Let us assume to the contrary that $X$ is first countable. Then especially $p = (0,0)$ has as a neighborhood base of open $W_n$, $n \in \mathbb N$.

For each $\sigma_i$ and each $m \in \mathbb N$ let $U_i^m = \{ (x,y) \in \sigma_i \mid x < 1/m \}$. This a basis of open neigborhoods of $p$ in $\sigma_i$.

Since $W_n \cap \sigma_i$ is an open neigborhood of $p$ in $\sigma_i$, there exists $r(n,i) \in \mathbb N$ such that $U_i^{r(n,i)} \subset W_n \cap \sigma_i$. Define

$$U^* = \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty U_i^{r(i,i) + 1}$$
This is an open subset of $X$ because the $U^* \cap \sigma_i =  U_i^{r(i,i) + 1}$ are open in $\sigma_i$. Clearly $p \in U^*$. Since the $W_n$ form a neighborhood base at $p$, there exists $n$ such that $W_n \subset U^*$. Thus for $i = n$
$$U_n^{r(n,n)} \subset  W_n \cap \sigma_n \subset U^* \cap \sigma_n = U_n^{r(n,n) + 1} .$$
This is false, thus are assumption was wrong.

The above proof is a variant of [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument).

Comment: @coudy Yes. $U$ is open iff $X \setminus U$ is closed iff all intersections $(X \setminus U) \cap \sigma$ are closed in  $\sigma$ iff all $\sigma \setminus (X \setminus U) \cap \sigma = U \cap \sigma$ are open in $\sigma$.

Comment: @coudy Another way to see it is this: The "simplicial topology" on $X$ is the final topology induced by the inclusions $\sigma \hookrightarrow X$, i.e. the finest topology on $X$ making all these inclusions continuous. You can describe continuity via preimages of closed sets or of open sets.